# How to not inherit the css from <ui:include>?

Tags: css, xhtml

Currently, Page.xhtml includes Menubar.xhtml. The Page.xhtml seems to inherit the menuBar.css from Menubar.xhtml. Can the content of Page.xhtml not inherit menuBar.css but use themeMain.css only?

Menubar.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:hx="http://www.ibm.com/jsf/html_extended">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/theme/primefaces-aristo/menuBar.css" />

<f:loadBundle basename="messages.MessageResources" var="msg" />

<tr>
    <td><img border="0" src="/BelsizeWeb/theme/new_header.png"
        width="930" height="85"></img></td>
</tr>
</ui:composition>
```

Page.xhtml

```
<h:head>
<title>Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="keywords" content="enter,your,keywords,here" />
<meta http-equiv="description"
    content="A short description of this page." />

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="#{request.contextPath}/theme/primefaces-aristo/themeMain.css" />

<f:view locale="en" />

<f:loadBundle basename="messages.MessageResources" var="msg" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
<h:form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" prependId="false">
    <ui:include src="../../theme/menubar.xhtml" />
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes keep the `<ui:composition>` tag inside or simply remove stylesheet inclusion from Menubar.xhtml, so the `<ui:include src>` tag will embed only the required markup. Everything that is outside the `<ui:composition>` tag will not be included.

Now you are including a stylesheet in the the body of the generated html, with unpredictable results.

Hope this helps.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:hx="http://www.ibm.com/jsf/html_extended">


<f:loadBundle basename="messages.MessageResources" var="msg" />

<tr>
    <td><img border="0" src="/BelsizeWeb/theme/new_header.png"
        width="930" height="85"></img></td>
</tr>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But I need the menuBar.css to style the Menubar.xhtml